# SQL Server select multiple values and return null if no value is found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query `SELECT TOP 1 Mat,Dat FROM TableLog WHERE Of=1 order by Id desc;` which might return nothing. So I get a result set like this:

```
Mat  |   Dat
```

I'd like to get NULL values instead of nothing like this:

```
Mat  |   Dat
NULL     NULL
```

I tried doing it with `SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Mat,Dat FROM TableLog WHERE Of=1 order by Id desc)` but it only works if I have one value in my select!

Any idea of how I could do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm.  This is tricky.  One method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(Mat) as Mat, MAX(Dat) as Dat
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Mat, Dat
      FROM TableLog
      WHERE Of = 1
      ORDER BY Id desc
     ) md;
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` is always guaranteed to return one row.

Comment: I tried it and it works perfectly, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 3):

This could also work and does not require an aggregation.

```
DECLARE @TableLog TABLE (
  Id INT,
  Mat INT,
  Dat INT,
  [Of] INT);

INSERT INTO @TableLog
VALUES (1, 2, 2, 2);

SELECT TOP (1) Mat, Dat
FROM (SELECT Mat, Dat, Id
      FROM @TableLog
      WHERE [Of] = 2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL) AS T
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

If you remove inserts, it bring back NULL value. Cannot tell whether this is more efficient than what Gordon Linoff suggested.

Comment: thank you for your answer, with the current size of my table I can't tell which query is more efficient. I'll try it again when it will be bigger and come back to this question if I see a difference!