# I need Total return NULL only If all values are NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A query like these

```
      SELECT A,B,C,D, (A+B+C+D) as TOTAL
      FROM TABLES
```

If A,B,C and D is NULL. i need to return NULL.
But if any one of the them is not NULL. Other will change from NULL to zero.
And total(a+b+c+d).

Now try this way

```
      SELECT A,B,.. CASE WHEN (A IS NULL) AND (B IS NULL) AND ... THEN NULL
                    ELSE ISNULL(A,0) + ISNULL(B,NULL) +... END
```

But it is so long and I have a lot of total in this whole query.
What the best way I can use for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server select multiple values and return null if no value is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892728/sql-server-select-multiple-values-and-return-null-if-no-value-is-found)

Answer (score 5):

The semantics you want are the same as those provided by `SUM`.

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,
       (SELECT SUM(val)
        FROM   (VALUES(A),
                      (B),
                      (C),
                      (D)) T (val)) AS Total
FROM   YourTable
```

Comment: Wow nice answer very elegant.

Answer (score 4):

I would use `COALESCE` function.

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to `NULL`.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(A,B,C,D) IS NOT NULL THEN
       COALESCE(A,0 ) + COALESCE(B,0 )+ COALESCE(C,0 ) + COALESCE(D,0 ) 
    END 
FROM TABLES
```

Answer (score 2):

[`COALESCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is a function that you can use:

```
SELECT A,B,.. 
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(A,B,C,D) IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ISNULL(A,0) + ISNULL(B,0) +... END
```

Comment: This is real close but I think has an issue because null + anything  is null so your else could be NULL